# Will be any version of TypeScript Obsolete?

Tags: typescript, deprecated, obsolete

I have a question: In the future, will any version of TypeScript be deprecated? I mean, if I'm using TypeScript 3.8 for some components, should I upgrade this components to TypeScript 4.x? or maybe we can keep these componentes without changes. There are some restrictions of obsolescence that we have to adhere to, hence my question.

Comment: You could possibly ask about specific language features but just asking about the language, as is, sounds too general. But even considering specific features, it's kind of like reading tea leaves, who knows what the language be in 5, 10 or 25 years. Is your perspective even that long?

Comment: Backwards incompatible changes in TypeScript are rare, so there's generally no harm in upgrading anyway.

Comment: "Obsolete" is a subjective non-technical term, e.g. we would definitely say that Java 5 is obsolete, but this does not have anything to do with whether Oracle declare it as such. Oracle might say Java 5 is no longer supported with bugfixes, although that's not quite the same thing. As for "deprecated", a *version* of something cannot be deprecated, rather a *feature* is deprecated if the developers announce that it will be removed in a future version.

Comment: @Thomas Backwards-incompatible changes in TS aren't rare - they happen in pretty much every minor version, it's just that they only tend to break backwards-compatibility for a small amount of code that is doing something atypical or unusual. For an example, you can see a list of all breaking changes in TS 4.6 -> 4.7 in the [changelog](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#breaking-changes).

Comment: @kaya3 Quite true, that's what I meant but failed to express, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

The term you're looking for is breaking changes, and breaking changes happen nearly every release. As an example, here's the breaking changes for the latest three releases:

- [Typescript 4.7 breaking changes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#breaking-changes)
- [Typescript 4.6 breaking changes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-6.html#breaking-changes)
- [Typescript 4.5 breaking changes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#breaking-changes)

If your components use those specific features in a way that isn't valid in a newer Typescript version, you'll get a compilation error when trying to compile your project using that newer version.

In my very subjective opinion, most of the time breaking changes fill in missing gaps in the language that were good to avoid to begin with. For example, [the breaking change for object rests over generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-6.html#object-rests-drop-unspreadable-members-from-generic-objects) in 4.6:

```
class Thing {
  someProperty = 42;
  someMethod() {
    // ...
  }
}
function foo<T extends Thing>(x: T) {
  let { someProperty, ...rest } = x;
  // Compiled successfully in Typescript 4.5, throws an error in Typescript 4.6 with: Property 'someMethod' does not exist on type 'Omit<T, "someProperty" | "someMethod">'.
  rest.someMethod();
}
```

The breaking change in this context could be looked at as a bugfix for the language, but it will require action from you to fix if you had code like this and then needed to target a newer version of Typescript.

Comment: *In my very subjective opinion* this looks like something that doesn't quite fit here. Not gonna downvote or upvote, just saying. It's not your fault, it's the question that provokes that kind of answers, though.